# What should i type in VCS root name and VCS root id

Tags: teamcity

I have remote git repository with single project (i expect 2 branches: dev & master) and now i try to create build configuration in TeamCity.

I can't figure out, what should i type in `VCS root name` & `VCS root ID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VCS root name is for your sake, as a display name so that you can re-use it in different build configurations (basically a name for your repo). As for the VCS root ID I'm not so sure, it's for internal reference I would think (You can generate this from the VCS root name, right?)

Answer (score 0):

VCS root name and id are pretty much there to identify a VCS. What's more important are the **Fetch URL** and **Branch specification** where in you need to put your git repository url which you want to clone. You can use **Branch specification** to define which branches you want to display in teamcity.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!